# GhostScript Path output/input error

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript, ghostscript.net, ghostscriptsharp

I'm using GS 32bits with the wrapper for C# .

This line works :

```
GhostscriptSharp.GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumb("a.pdf" , "a.jpg", 1, 100, 100, 50, 50);
```

But this line doesn't work

```
GhostscriptSharp.GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumb("a.pdf" , "C:\\a.jpg", 1, 100, 100, 50, 50);
```

How GS handle the in/out path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute paths are a bit problematic. I've solved my problem by using relative paths.

```
GhostscriptSharp.GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumb("a.pdf" , "thumbs/a.jpg", 1, 100, 100, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Don't use backslash, use forward slash. I am presuming that Ghostscript sharp (which is not maintained by Artifex) simply passes the path to Ghostscript. Ghostscript will accept forward slash path separators.